# iOS Xcode: How to keep one background image for launch screen storyboard which will work for both orientations on iPad

Tags: xcode, autolayout, xcode8, size-classes, launch-screen

I am designing my app's launch image using "Launch Screen" storyboard. My idea is to add a `UIImageView` to the canvas, make it fill the screen and apply auto-layout to fit for different sizes.

But the problem is when I assign a image with pixel size 1536x2048 to the image view, it looks good on iPad portrait view. But, looks odd in iPad landscape mode as it gets stretched.

Is there any way to assign 2 different images to image view for portrait and landscape? Or else, please suggest if there are any other better ways to do. The requirement is to design a launch screen which should look fine on all iPhones and iPads. Again, iPad supports both orientations.

Comment: Yes. But, how to set 2 images for one image view based on size class? Again, we can't differentiate between iPad portrait and landscape using size classes.

Comment: Ohh is it possible? I didn't try this.

Comment: Can you please post your idea as full answer?

Comment: But I think iPad size class is width-regular, height-regular in both orientations. It may be difficult to install/ remove views based on orientation of iPad.

Comment: ok, I just tried it it didn't work between orientations. Only between devices.

Comment: So, your solution doesn't hold good?

Comment: use this instead: [detect orientation ios](https://www.google.ca/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=detect+orinetaion+ios&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=s-7fV6X3C6yC8Qeskpz4Bg). Then use if (landscape) ->  create imageView with specific (height + width) and add it as subView. else  imageView.removeFromsuperView and  create a new imageView with different size

Comment: It's about Launch Screen storyboard. I can't add any customization programmatically.

Comment: You can create a new storyboard with customized code and set it as launch screen http://imgur.com/a/uLnrN

Comment: I thought launch screen storyboard can't be assigned to custom classes.

Comment: LaunchScreen is just a regular storyboard that with regular View controller

Answer (score 1):

Try using size classes with 2 imageViews.

Select iPad -> make orientation landscape. Then make 1st imageView installed for landscape and at the same time disable the 2nd imageView, then switch to portrait and do the opposite what you have done.

Edit:

The solution I posted would help if you want to have different images for iPhone and iPads.

Use this instead: [detect orientation ios](https://www.google.ca/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=detect+orinetaion+ios&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=s-7fV6X3C6yC8Qeskpz4Bg).

```
  if (landscape){
 let imageView with specific (height + width)
 view.addSubView(imageView) 

  } else {

imageView.removeFromsuperView 
create a new imageView with different size 
addToSubView()
}
```